# Error Using Ruby generator in Rails (not Rails::Generator)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, generator

**Edit: To be clear, I'm trying to use this [kind of generator](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/generator/rdoc/classes/Generator.html) (i.e. with a 'yield' statement) not a Rails generator.**

I have the following (simplified) initializer mixin in a Rails project that I could use some help with. What I wanted to do was create a generator to track Twitter API calls (this is just for debugging, I know about rate_limit_status).

```
require 'generator'
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
module TwitterMixin
  def get_auth
    @auth ||= Twitter::HTTPAuth.new(ENV['TWITTER_USER'], ENV['TWITTER_PASS'])
  end
  def count
    @counter ||= generator.new
    @counter.yield
  end
  def client
    p "#{count} Twitter API calls this iteration"
    @client ||= Twitter::Base.new(get_auth)
  end
end
```

The problem is that I'm getting the following error:

```
dlopen(/Users/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/json-1.2.0/ext/json/ext/generator.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Users/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/json-1.2.0/ext/json/ext/generator.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Users/john/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/json-1.2.0/ext/json/ext/generator.bundle
```

Which seems like a collision with the json generator, which is probably in a more enclosing scope.
**The main question is how to I ensure a Ruby standard library class (specifically the generator class) is called?**

I'm still new to Ruby, BTW, and searching for "generators in Rails" is pretty dominated by Rails::Generator, so this may be fairly obvious. Also, I'm open to more elegant solutions to this problem that I may have missed. Thanks.

Comment: generator is part of the Ruby 1.8 standard library, there's some documentation at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/generator/rdoc/index.html if that's any use. It's not in 1.9, though - I haven't fully understood why.

Comment: I imagine it's because you can use yield directly? Not sure how you'd subclass it though. Probably just build yield into a method of the class like Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me reject my earlier answer and say that it was rather stupid of me to use "yield" thinking that it was a generator builtin similar to Python's yield statement. I learned today at our first [RubyGorge](http://rubygorge.org) meeting about Ruby blocks. Thus, I think I still seek a solution to this problem.

Comment: Selecting this as an answer because after learning more about Ruby (hand about a week under my belt at this question) I've realized that I was asking the wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a ruby gem on your system called "generator"?  It sounds like ruby is having trouble locating the gem based on your require.  If you're using the Rubigen generator, then you need:

```
require 'rubigen'
```

and so forth.  try running:

```
gem list generator
```

If it doesn't pull anything up, you're probably calling the library by the wrong name.

Comment: didn't realize I had to use a gem, I was thinking that it would be a standard library class as in: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Generator.html Maybe I'm misunderstanding something about the standard library?

Comment: Oh, I now see that might be more name collision with Rails::Generator which is why I can't find any solutions searching.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to build a generator, you can use the yield method directly, which I didn't realize. This code works.

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.
module TwitterMixin
  def get_auth
    @auth ||= Twitter::HTTPAuth.new(ENV['TWITTER_USER'], ENV['TWITTER_PASS'])
  end
  def count
    @num ||= 0
    while true
      num += 1
      yield num
    end
  end
  def client
    p "#{count} Twitter API calls this iteration"
    @client ||= Twitter::Base.new(get_auth)
  end
end
```